"undefined reference to" using esp-idf
I am facing a problem as stated in the title,as follows:
This is my project structure:
main/
├── app/
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── led_blink.c
│   ├── led_blink.h
├── common/
│   ├── defines.h
│   ├── includes.h
│   ├── libraries.h
├── main.c
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── .gitignore
├── README.md
├── sdkconfig

In my common/defines.h:
#define LED_PIN 2

In my common/includes.h:
#include "libraries.h"
#include "defines.h"

In my common/libraries.h:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "app/led_blink.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

In my app/led_blink.c:
#include "led_blink.h"

static uint8_t s_led_state = 0;

void blink_led(void)
{
    gpio_set_level(LED_PIN, s_led_state);
    s_led_state = !s_led_state;
    // Delay for 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
}

void configure_led(void)
{
    gpio_reset_pin(LED_PIN);
    /* Set the GPIO as a push/pull output */
    gpio_set_direction(LED_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
}

In my app/led_blink.h:
void blink_led(void);
void configure_led(void);

In my main.c:
#include "common/includes.h"

void app_main(void)
{
    configure_led();
    while (1)
    {
        blink_led();
    }
}

This is the Cmakefiles
app/CMakeLists.txt:
idf_component_register(SRCS "led_blink.c"
                        INCLUDE_DIRS "." "../common")

main/CMakeLists.txt:
idf_component_register(SRCS "main.c"
                    INCLUDE_DIRS "." "common" "app" )

This is the log problem:
.../main/libmain.a(main.c.obj):(.literal.app_main+0x0): undefined reference to `configure_led'
.../main/libmain.a(main.c.obj):(.literal.app_main+0x4): undefined reference to `blink_led'
...main/main.c:5:(.text.app_main+0x3): undefined reference to `configure_led'
.../main/main.c:8:(.text.app_main+0x9): undefined reference to `blink_led'

I tried to read the document on ESP-idf, but no help, can anyone help me, thanks in advance

Is led_blink.c supposed to be a part of a standalone library or part of the main program ?

I don't know what idf_component_register does but you don't appear to be linking your code together. Please don't tag c++ for c questions

it is part of the main program @JoëlHecht

@Khoa Nguyễn, if it is part of the main program, I suppose it should appear in SRCS list of the main CMakefile.
